# How do I render a list in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am stuck with the array in node.js. I have created mix array. And I am trying to pass the array to html file by using render module. Also inside my html file I want to loop through the array and display all the information inside the array.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    app.set('view engine','ejs');


    app.get('/home', function(req, res, next){
        var student1 = ['charles', 25,'Engineer'];
        var student2 = [ 'Ali', 24, 'Business'];
        res.render('profile', {student1:student1, student2:student2
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000);
```

My html codes.

```
 <body>

    <h1>Student Details</h1>
    <ul>
        <% student1.forEach(function(item){ %>

    <li><%= item %></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: You are using arrays and objects incorrectly. Each of your  students is an array when it should be an object. And your students is an object, when it should be an array (of student objects).

Comment: How do I change the student object to an array?

Comment: You don't have a student object yet. Example: `const s1 = {name:'Bob', age:23}; const s2 = {name:'Jane', age:21}; const students = [s1, s2];`

Comment: I did all of those but i cant seem to loop through it in html.

Comment: you can use `template engine` like `ejs` rather than using `static files`

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I am using ejs instead of html.